# How do I covert some column's value by using SQL on MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a table named Employee in my database, the structure is as shown below:

```
Id   email                      phone        name
1    user@gmail.com           +7845690001    Jonney
2    Nortex.zone@gmail.com    +7845690781    North
```

I have some data that I want to mask, for example `+7845690001` to `+7845690***`. Full version as below.

```
Id   email                      phone        name
1    u**r@gmail.com           +7845690***    J****y
2    N*********e@gmail.com    +7845690***    N***h
```

I managed to do this for name and phone:

```
Select CONCAT(MID(phone, 1, LENGTH(phone) - 3), '***') as new_phone,
CONCAT(LEFT(name,1),REPEAT("*",LENGTH(name)-2),RIGHT(name,1)) as new_name from employee.
```

How can I do this for email?

Comment: I have achieved phone using this.
CONCAT(MID(phone, 1, LENGTH(phone) - 3), '***') as phone_new

Comment: "I need" isn't a question. [Edit] your post an add what you have tried and an explanation what went wrong with it and where exactly you need help.

Comment: @sticky bit , I have added what I have tried it in comment. Please check.

Comment: MySql version 8 has REGEX_REPLACE(), but earlier versions do not. What version do you use? Please [edit] your question to let us know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer:

```
Select CONCAT(MID(phone, 1, LENGTH(phone) - 3), '***') as new_phone,
CONCAT(LEFT(name,1),REPEAT("*",LENGTH(name)-2),RIGHT(name,1)) as new_name,CONCAT(CONCAT(left(email,1),REPEAT("*",LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(email, "@", 1))-2),RIGHT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(email, "@", 1),1)),'@',SUBSTRING_INDEX(email,'@',-1)) as new_email from employee
```

Thanks all. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **CONCAT** and **SubSTRING** functions in mysql.
The email and name has the same feature, use the same thing for name and change digits based your requirement.

```
SELECT CONCAT(LEFT(`name`, 1),"***",RIGHT(`name`, 1)) as cname, CONCAT(LEFT(`email `, 1),"***",SUBSTRING(`email `, LOCATE("@", `email `)-1, LENGTH(`email `)-LOCATE("@", `email `)-1)) as cemail , CONCAT(LEFT(`phone`, 8),"***") as cphone FROM `test4`
```

EDITTED -----------------

To fill by the exact number of characters you can use LPAD function. For name you can do:

```
SELECT CONCAT(LEFT(`name `,1),LPAD(RIGHT(`name `,1),LENGTH(`name `)-1,'*')) FROM `test4`
```

Use LOCATE and change indexes based on upper query for email.

Comment: Not working. I want exact * for character. Jonney = J****y, like this.

Comment: It changed based your requirement.

Comment: Don't use same * character by your name, It gives information to your reader. Use fixed * character like other application which concerned about security.

Comment: Yes, I understand but I want exact same. :)

Comment: @user14059282 I edited the answer for exact number of * instead of characters. But be careful this method can give information to hackers.

Answer (score 0):

You can work with MySQL's string functions: `LEFT()`,`RIGHT()`,`LENGTH()`, `REPEAT()`, and `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` .

I'll just do it for `email`:

```
WITH
input(Id,email,phone,name) AS (
          SELECT 1 , 'user@gmail.com'        ,'+7845690001','Jonney'
UNION ALL SELECT 2 , 'Nortex.zone@gmail.com' ,'+7845690781','North'
)
SELECT
  id
, -- the leftmost single character or "email"
    LEFT(email,1)
 -- repeat "*" for the length of the part of "email" before "@" minus 2
 || REPEAT('*',LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(email,'@',1))-2)
 -- the rightmost single character of the part of "email" before "@"
 || RIGHT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(email,'@',1),1)
 -- hard-wire "@"
 ||'@'
 -- the part of "email" from the end of the string back to "@"
 ||SUBSTRING_INDEX(email,'@',-1)
 AS email
FROM input
-- out  id |         email         
-- out ----+-----------------------
-- out   1 | u**r@gmail.com
-- out   2 | N*********e@gmail.com
-- out (2 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

A REGEXP_REPLACE can also do the trick. Here is how to do it for the **email**:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(email, '(?!^).(?=[^@]+@)', '*') AS masked_email
FROM Employee;
```

Explanation:

(?!^) we make sure that the matching character is not at the beginning of the string and that way we skip the first character.

. matches the character to be replaced

(?=[^@]+@) we will stop at a sequence which is any character that is NOT @, then followed by @.

Every single character which is matched between the two will then be replaced with a * (the third parameter) by the function.

For the **phone number** I will show a much simpler solution:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(phone, '[0-9]{3}$', '***') AS masked_phone
FROM Employee;
```

[0-9]{3} matches exactly three digits

$ tells that they must be at the end of the string.

We then replace them with three stars. Please note that this solution is assuming that you always store the phone numbers in a way that they always end with three digits. So for example if I enter a phone like "555-55-55-55", nothing will be masked. If you do not always insert the phones normalized in the same format, then you must think about something more complicated (like fetch digit - fetch zero or more non digits - fetch digit - fetch zero or more non digits - fetch digit - end of string, then replace whatever is matched with three *-s). Like this:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(phone, '[0-9][^0-9]*[0-9][^0-9]*[0-9][^0-9]*$', '***') AS masked_phone
FROM Employee;
```

Here [0-9] means a single digit and [^0-9]* means zero or more non-digits. And of course the same thing can be simplified by grouping the digit and the zero or more non-digits in one group which is then repeated exactly three times:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(phone, '([0-9][^0-9]*){3}$', '***') AS masked_phone
FROM Employee;
```

And for the **name**, we can do the following:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(name, '(?!^).(?=.+$)', '*') AS masked_name
FROM Employee;
```

So again we skip the first character, than match and replace every character until the last character of the string.

IMPORTANT: In the above examples we preserve the length of the strings. If you want higher anonymity, you can fetch the data in groups and then replace a desired group with a single *. For example for the e-mail:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(email, '^(.)(.)+([^@]@.+)$', '\\1*\\3') AS masked_email
FROM Employee;
```

This will replace john@gmail.dom to j*n@gmail.dom and margareth@gmail.dom to m*h@gmail.dom. So it masked the length as well. Explanation:

^ is the start of the string

(.) is our first group. It it s single character

(.)+ is the second group. It's one or more characters.

([^@]@.+) is our third group. It is a single character which is NOT @, followed by @, then followed by one or more characters (any).

We replace that with \1 (the first group), followed by a single *, followed by \3 (the third group).